# javascript, calendar

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to ask if there's anyway I can 'shift' the calender to the right side of the page? Because I realized that it can only be displayed on the left hand side. I do not really know how to 'shift' it to the right hand side... Neither do I know how to put css in to do it.

Here's the code to make the calendar...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//  SET ARRAYS
        var day_of_week = new Array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
        var month_of_year = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');

//  DECLARE AND INITIALIZE VARIABLES
        var Calendar = new Date();

        var year = Calendar.getFullYear();      // Returns year
        var month = Calendar.getMonth();    // Returns month (0-11)
        var today = Calendar.getDate();    // Returns day (1-31)
        var weekday = Calendar.getDay();    // Returns day (1-31)

        var DAYS_OF_WEEK = 7;    // "constant" for number of days in a week
        var DAYS_OF_MONTH = 31;    // "constant" for number of days in a month
        var cal;    // Used for printing

        Calendar.setDate(1);    // Start the calendar day at '1'
        Calendar.setMonth(month);    // Start the calendar month at now


/* VARIABLES FOR FORMATTING
NOTE: You can format the 'BORDER', 'BGCOLOR', 'CELLPADDING', 'BORDERCOLOR'
      tags to customize your caledanr's look. */

    var TR_start = '<TR>';
    var TR_end = '</TR>';
    var highlight_start = '<TD WIDTH="10"><TABLE CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=1 BGCOLOR=DEDEFF BORDERCOLOR=CCCCCC><TR><TD WIDTH=5><B><CENTER>';
    var highlight_end   = '</CENTER></TD></TR></TABLE></B>';
    var TD_start = '<TD WIDTH="1"><CENTER>';
    var TD_end = '</CENTER></TD>';

/* BEGIN CODE FOR CALENDAR
NOTE: You can format the 'BORDER', 'BGCOLOR', 'CELLPADDING', 'BORDERCOLOR'
tags to customize your calendar's look.*/

    cal =  '<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 BORDERCOLOR=BBBBBB><TR><TD>';
    cal += '<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1>' + TR_start;
    cal += '<TD COLSPAN="' + DAYS_OF_WEEK + '" BGCOLOR="#EFEFEF"><CENTER><B>';
    cal += month_of_year[month]  + ' ' + year + '</B>' + TD_end + TR_end;
    cal += TR_start;

// LOOPS FOR EACH DAY OF WEEK
    for(index=0; index < DAYS_OF_WEEK; index++)
    {

// BOLD TODAY'S DAY OF WEEK
        if(weekday == index)
        cal += TD_start + '<B>' + day_of_week[index] + '</B>' + TD_end;

// PRINTS DAY
        else
            cal += TD_start + day_of_week[index] + TD_end;
            }

            cal += TD_end + TR_end;
            cal += TR_start;

// FILL IN BLANK GAPS UNTIL TODAY'S DAY
    for(index=0; index < Calendar.getDay(); index++)
    cal += TD_start + '' + TD_end;

// LOOPS FOR EACH DAY IN CALENDAR
    for(index=0; index < DAYS_OF_MONTH; index++)
    {
        if( Calendar.getDate() > index )
        {
              // RETURNS THE NEXT DAY TO PRINT
              week_day =Calendar.getDay();

              // START NEW ROW FOR FIRST DAY OF WEEK
              if(week_day == 0)
              cal += TR_start;

      if(week_day != DAYS_OF_WEEK)
      {

          // SET VARIABLE INSIDE LOOP FOR INCREMENTING PURPOSES
          var day  = Calendar.getDate();

          // HIGHLIGHT TODAY'S DATE
          if( today==Calendar.getDate() )
          cal += highlight_start + day + highlight_end + TD_end;

          // PRINTS DAY
          else
          cal += TD_start + day + TD_end;
          }

      // END ROW FOR LAST DAY OF WEEK
      if(week_day == DAYS_OF_WEEK)
      cal += TR_end;
      }

      // INCREMENTS UNTIL END OF THE MONTH
      Calendar.setDate(Calendar.getDate()+1);

    }// end for loop

    cal += '</TD></TR></TABLE></TABLE>';

    //  PRINT CALENDAR
    document.write(cal);

    //  End -->

</script>
```

Comment: We can't answer this based on the massive wall of code you've provided. We'd need to see the resulting HTML. Chances are it's something as simple as "float:right;" or "margin:0 0 0 auto" applied to the calendar's container.

Comment: `<Center>`...`<table>` for non tabular data..hold on, I'm going to go go kill myself, I'll be right back.

Comment: You should not implement that by yourself. Take a look at http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/ for exemple.

Comment: @Alex JL: A calendar is tabular data, isn't it? But still, `document.write`, the `<CENTER>` tag, and a lack of locally scoped variables show that this is an old script that does not follow current best practices.

Comment: @RC: Good point that there are good alternatives available now to what is found on http://javascript.internet.com/ and other sites.

Comment: @idealmachine I'm sorry, it's too late for me to consider reason, facts or logic. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Add an align=right to the table definition on line 38.

So you'll have:

```
cal =  '<TABLE ALIGN=RIGHT BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 BORDERCOLOR=BBBBBB><TR><TD>';
```

Instead of:

```
cal =  '<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 BORDERCOLOR=BBBBBB><TR><TD>';
```

Comment: I believe dated markup to tweak a dated script (no pun intended) is OK. In CSS (the current best-practice way of doing it) we would use `float: right;` though.